# how can i solved it org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /stud_add.jsp (line: 113, column: 119) Unterminated &lt;form:option tag

Tags: spring, for-loop, jsp

```
<form:select class="form-control" path="batch_id" id="genderOptions">
   <%for(BatchModel qt:batchlist){%>
     <form:option value='<%=qt!=null?qt.getBatch_id():""%>'     <%=studlist.getStud_id()!=0?studlist.getBatch_id().getBatch_id()==qt.getBatch_id()?"selected='selected'":"":"" %>/><%=qt.getBname()!=null?qt.getBname():"" %>
      <form:errors path="batch_id" cssClass="error" />
       <%--   <option value="<%=(String.valueOf(qt.getBatch_id())!=null)?qt.getBatch_id():""%>"><%=(String.valueOf(qt.getBname())!=null)?qt.getBname():""%></option>
       --%>
       <% } %>
    </form:select>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you have closed the `<form:option/>` tag incorrectly. Close it like :

```
<form:select path="country">
   <form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select ---"/>
   <form:options items="${countryList}" />
</form:select>
```

By providing the expression for setting the `selected` attribute tag , you are not properly closing the  . Try providing the `selected` value using an expression like what you have done for `value` attribute.Like :

```
selected="<%=studlist.getStud_id()!=0?studlist.getBatch_id().getBatch_id()==qt.getBatch_id()?"selected":"":"" %>"
```